# need to convert each line of file in to separate files in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have text file with 2 to 3 lines of text, each line is a path. I have to take that file as an input and each line has to be converted to a seperate file. Please help me with the syntax to do with in powershell

below is an input file content

Explore/XXx/XXXX/APC-SMTXXX.AI_SERVICE_CONNECTOR.xml
Explore/XXX/XXX/APC-SMTPYYY_SERVICE_CONNECTOR.xml

each line has to be in 2 separate text files

Comment: Seems pretty straight forward. You can use `Get-Content` with some loop, and `Out-File` for the export. The syntax you can get by running `Get-Help cmdlet-name`.

Comment: the out-file parameter works with width(Characters), but im not sure with the characters. I have to read  line by line, each line in to one separate file. Sorry Im new to powershell :( Please excuse if my question is silly